# MySQL - get all column averages also with a 'total' average

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table which looks like this:

```
id  load_transit    load_standby
1   40              20
2   30              15        
3   50              10
```

I need to do the following calculations:

```
load_transit_mean = (40+30+50)/3 = 40
load_standby_mean = (20+15+10)/3 = 15
total_mean = (40+15)/2 = 27.5
```

Is it possible to do this in a single query? What would the best design be?

I need my answer to be scalable (the real design has more rows and columns), and able to handle some rows containing NULL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this would do it:

```
SELECT AVG(Load_transit)
     , AVG(load_standby)
     , (AVG(Load_transit) + AVG(load_standby))/2.0
FROM table
```

The `AVG()` function handles NULL's in that it ignores them, if you want the NULL row to be counted in your denominator you can replace `AVG()` with `SUM()` over `COUNT(*)`, ie:

```
   SUM(load_transit)/COUNT(*)
```

Regarding scalability, manually listing them out like above is probably the simplest solution.